# How do I execute a method every 1 Minute for the purpose of updating my App (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I had a very simple question, I'm trying to update my app with data from my database every 1 minute. I have a method called "SendRequest" which collects the data from my database.

How would I execute this method every 1 minute? I'm not sure where to start with it.

Thanks!

Comment: with the use of alarmManager Or if you call any service/Api from server you can use cron job

Answer (score 1):

First add this to your manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".NetWatcher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".location_service"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

After that add this two classes in your project

public class location_service extends Service {

```
LocationManager locationManager;
AlarmManager alarmMgr;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreate(){

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, NetWatcher.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // Use inexact repeating which is easier on battery (system can phase events and not wake at exact times)
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1000*60*1,pendingIntent);    

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // Write your method here

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

And

public class NetWatcher extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //start service

           Intent in = new Intent(context, location_service.class);
           context.startService(in);


}
```

}

After that write your method inside onStartCommand. start servise from your main activity first time

Intent in = new Intent(context, location_service.class);
 context.startService(in);

it will run background mode also.

Answer (score 1):

**It work In android**

Put Your sendRequest method in a thread

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   Handler customHandler = new Handler();
   customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

           public void run() {


                //enter "sendRequest" method here 

                }



               customHandler.postDelayed(this, 60000);//you can put 60000(1 minut)

           }



       };
```

the above code will send request in every minut

Answer (score 0):

**You can acheive it like this:**

```
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            SendRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i'll now fix it